# In the derivation of centre of mass, what is the basis of assumption a point having same acceleration as the body?

Tags: mass, rigid-body-dynamics

In the derivation of centre of mass, we assume that a point $X$ exists such that its acceleration is the same as acceleration of the whole body. And as the derivation proceeds, this point comes out to be the centre of mass.

But why are we sure, in the first place, that such a point exists?
And why only one such point?

Comment: In classical mechanics it's a result from the mathematical definition of the system, as is the uniqueness of the point.  We know that works because we've been successfully applying it in engineering (and walking and running) for centuries.  What more is there to say ?

Comment: @StephenG I think I was unable to convey the right query. I have edited my question.

Comment: *which* derivation? As you can see, there's multiple ways to go about things, and lack of clarity about what line of argument you're talking about directly harms your question here.

Comment: In general, the body can be rotating and every part of it has a *different* acceleration. So your statement that “we assume that a point $X$ exists such that its acceleration is the same as acceleration of the whole body” is false and indicates a misunderstanding of the center of mass.

Answer (score 1):

The center of mass is simply a weighted average where the weighting is the mass. From experience with other weighted averages we know the general criteria for such formulas, and from our physics knowledge we know that the physical quantities satisfy those criteria.

Specifically, the set of data (positions) must be non empty. The weights (masses) must be non negative. And the sum of the weights (masses) must be non zero. All of these are fulfilled, so we know that the center of mass exists and is unique.

Comment: I think I was unable to convey the right query. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

We have defined a point such that
(M1 + M2 + ....  ..)Xcom = M1X1 + M2X2 .......   (Remember we have defined this point like not derived).Here all X represent position vector. Here the variable is only Xcom is the only variable so it is like 1 linear equation and one variable so a unique solution.

Now differentiating both sides with respect to time

(M1 + M2 + .........)Acom = M1A1 + M1A2 + ..........(Here all A represent acceleration vector) . Here also it is like 1 equation and 1 variable and we have found the unique solution to it.

It is a coincidence that our defined point show this property